# pymunk custom complex creatures

Tags: python, pygame, chipmunk, pymunk

I am trying to create an evolution simulator, something very similar to [this](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/377698). As for tools I am using pymunk physics simulator with pygame.

My creatures consist of few circles with their respective bodies fixed together with DampedSprings as muscles. Springs give me a nice effect of expanding and contracting muscles however they do not hold their "angular position". What I mean by that is that when creature is spawned with triangular shape, in the moment it falls on the ground the top node just falls on the ground -> does not hold its shape.
[spawned creature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTrg0.png)
[deformated creature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifHm9.png)

What I wish would happen is that the creature would hold its shape when it falls down on the ground = the top node would stay at the top like it is at the moment of spawn while still maintaining the ability to simulate variable length of muscle.

Anybody have an idea how could I solve this issue please ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is the springs are not strong enough to hold back. But maybe if you make the springs stronger (stiffer?) the effect doesnt look well?

One idea I think you can try is to add a DampedRotarySpring (http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.constraint.html#pymunk.constraint.DampedRotarySpring) as well for each DampedSpring you have. That way you have one spring working to keep angles, and one to keep distance.

Comment: I have thought about both of the things you wrote, definitely glad for the suggestion. I already tried to make them stiffer, partially helped and partially made it worse. It helped in the structural side but then i was unable to make the muscles (springs) look like they are contracting and lengthening since the springs were too strong (did not try to increase the power of muscles though)

I wanted to implement the RotarySprings in the moment I saw them but since the DampedSprings do not have pymunk.body I can not connect DampedSprings with nodes using DampedRotarySprings.

Comment: Another problem with making DampedSprings stiffer is that it satisfies my goals just partially. When the creature spawns with triangular shape however the top node is not above center of gravity but more to the side than one of the base nodes it would still fall down since it acts like it has bearing in the center of node and it just rotates inside. What my goal would be is that the whole creature would flip over and some other two nodes would create base of the creature. Hopefully I described it well enough.

Comment: I dont think I understand why rotary spring could be used? My thinking was to add one spring between each pair of bodies you already have.